# How do I remove 'unsafe-eval' error from the Content Security Policy?

Tags: javascript, node.js, server, backend, content-security-policy

I am running a local backend server using NodeJS but I always get this Content Security Policy error

[image: 1]

```
[Report Only] Refused to compile or instantiate WebAssembly module because 'unsafe-eval' is not an allowed source of script in the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self'".
```

I tried adding 'unsafe-eval' into my app using CSP package but i still get this error.

`csp.extend(app, { policy: { directives: { 'default-src': ['self'], 'style-src': ['self', 'unsafe-inline', 'https:'],'font-src': ['self', 'https://fonts.gstatic.com'], 'script-src': 'self', 'unsafe-inline', 'unsafe-eval', 'data', 'blob', 'ws://localhost:56558/', ], }, }, });`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most likely explanation is that you have multiple CSPs. Adding another CSP can only make it stricter. Check your response headers for a csp with "script-src 'self';" and change/remove it.